# Postgres and PyCharm and hung transactions

Tags: postgresql, transactions, vagrant, pycharm, freeze

I keep running into this issue where my postgresql database hangs because I didn't finish a transaction while debugging in PyCharm.

The log has several of these messages:

```
[16:30:40 PDT] unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction
```

Now the database is hung and I don't know how to recover from it other than shutting down the database (vagrant halt; vagrant up)

Is there any way to clear those stuck transactions so I don't have to go through stopping and restarting the database?

Thanks for any info

Comment: minor but you can run `vagrant reload` would be same as doing halt + up. and also you can just run `service postgresql restart` to restart only the service without having to restart the whole vm. and what is giving `service postgresql status` is the db still up ?

Comment: I will try this now.  That is a better idea, thanks.  On my system it was 'sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql-9.2 restart'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution here:

```
 SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity ORDER BY client_addr ASC, query_start ASC;
```

will list all your hung/idle transactions, then you can run

```
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(3592)
```

using the pid listed in the table.

and it is much faster than rebooting vagrant or postgresql